# Unity iPhone app size is too big

Tags: unity-game-engine

I built a unity game for iPhone which gave an app size of 288 MB. So tried with an **empty unity project**. Initially it generated app of size 33 MB. But after googling i could reduce it to **19.2 MB**.

The changes i made:
1. Release build instead of debug build.
2. Target Device: only iPhone(in Unity settings).
3. Target Platform: armv7

The device log from unity showed:

Mono dependencies included in the build
mscorlib.dll

Textures      0.0 kb     0.0%
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0%
Animations    0.0 kb     0.0%
Sounds        0.0 kb     0.0%
Shaders       0.0 kb     0.0%
Other Assets  0.0 kb     0.0%
Levels        6.7 kb     0.3%
Scripts       0.0 kb     0.0%
Included DLLs 2.4 mb     99.4%
File headers  8.0 kb     0.3%
Complete size 2.4 mb     100.0%

The package contents of my app has the **unix executable** with size **13.3 MB** and Data 5.7 MB.

Is there any thing i must change in unity settings or Xcode to reduce the app size further? Please help me.

Comment: Way more useful would be the log of your **actual** game. The list you included just shows 2.4 mb for DLLs, which you probably cannot remove, and it's nowhere near your game's size of 288 MB.

Comment: The list i showed is for the empty unity project which is now **19.2 MB**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the Unity Pro iPhone Pro license you could change the stripping level to *use micro mscorlib*. Read [Optimizing the Size of the Built iOS Player](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html) for more information.

In XCode the GCC 4.2 *Code Generation / Optimisation Level* should be *Fastest, Smallest (-Os)* - Unity3d will do that for your release builds in general.

Another point of interest are textures, audio and other resources. If you don't need iPad resolution  you might be able to reduce the size of your images. Check that all your images comply with the POT rule (Power Of Two) i.e. 128x128, 256x256, ... so that Unity3D can use PVRTC hardware compression for building iOS player. Non POT images will end up as uncompressed true color images.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying with a trial version of unity. As per your suggestion i changed my compiler to LLVM GCC4.2(mine was apple llvm 3.0). Now my app size is **19.1 MB**. Will licensing help to reduce the app size much?

Comment: As stated in the manual (s. link) an empty project of 13 MB can be reduced to 6 MB with all optimisations turned on. Anyway, Apple has increased the limit for purchases over cellular networks up to 50 MB. See: [Higher Limit for Over-the-Air Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=03202012a). So you can lean back and focus on performance tuning :-)

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I changed the stripping levels to "use micro mscorlib".This reduced my app size to **12.3 MB**.